# Why does the parser work but return null data when I try to print it out?

Tags: java, eclipse, xml-parsing

The program is suposed to print all the elements previously parsed from an .xml file.
It includes 3 java classes: the main, the parser and some Object model.

It seems to work and doesn't throw any error, but when i try to print the data recovered, it looks like it never saves that data (and so it print "null" instead of the String values)

I put some print statements to see where was the error, but it looks like all is fully working and I'm really missing something small but important.

The code for each class is:

Main

```java
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Parser parser = new Parser();

        try {
            parsearFich(parser);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    private static void parsearFich(Parser parser) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        parser.parseFicherosXml("biblioteca.xml");
        parser.parseDocument();
        parser.printLibro();

    }

}
```

The parser class named "Parser"

```java
public class Parser {
    private Document dom = null;
    private ArrayList<Libro> libros = null;

    public Parser() {
        libros = new ArrayList<Libro>();
    }

    public void parseFicherosXml(String fichero) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fichero);
        Reader rd = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
        InputSource isrc = new InputSource(rd);
        isrc.setEncoding("UTF-8");

        dom = db.parse(isrc);
    }

    public void parseDocument() {

        Element doc = dom.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("libro");

        if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0 ) {
            for (int i = 0; i< nl.getLength(); i++) {
                Element e1 = (Element)  nl.item(i);
                Libro l = getLibro(e1);
                libros.add(l);
            }
        }
    }


    private Libro getLibro(Element libro) {

        String editor = getTextValue(libro,"editor");
        String titulo = getTextValue(libro,"titulo");
        String pags = getTextValue(libro,"paginas");
        String anyo = getAributeValue(libro,"titulo");

        NodeList autores = libro.getElementsByTagName("nombre");
        String lista = "";

        for (int i =0; i < autores.getLength(); i++) {
            Element e = (Element) autores.item(i);
            lista = lista + " , " + e.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        }

        Libro l1 = new Libro();
        return l1;
    }

    private String getAributeValue(Element libro, String string) {

        String valor = null;
        NodeList nl = libro.getElementsByTagName(string);

        if (nl != null && nl.getLength()>0) {
            Element e1 = (Element)nl.item(0);
            valor = e1.getAttribute("anyo");
        }

        return valor;
    }

    private String getTextValue(Element libro, String string) {
        String valor = null;
        NodeList nl = libro.getElementsByTagName(string);

        if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
            Element e1 = (Element) nl.item(0);
            valor = e1.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        }
        return valor;
    }

    public void printLibro() {
        Iterator<Libro> it = libros.iterator();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Libro l = it.next();
            sb.append(l.toString() + "\n");

        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }

}
```

And the Object class (Libro)

```java
public class Libro implements Serializable {

    private String titulo;
    private String autor;
    private String anyo;
    private String editor;
    private String paginas;
    private String id;

    public Libro(){

    }

    public Libro(String titulo,String autor,String anyo, String editor,String paginas,String id) {

        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.anyo = anyo;
        this.editor = editor;
        this.paginas = paginas;
        this.id = id;

    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(String autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public String getAnyo() {
        return anyo;
    }

    public void setAnyo(String anyo) {
        this.anyo = anyo;
    }

    public String getEditor() {
        return editor;
    }

    public void setEditor(String editor) {
        this.editor = editor;
    }

    public String getPaginas() {
        return paginas;
    }

    public void setPaginas(String paginas) {
        this.paginas = paginas;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String toString(){
        String s = "Título: " + titulo + " Autor: " + autor + "Editor: " + editor + " Páginas: " + paginas + " Año publicación: " + anyo;
        return s;
    }
}
```

Also, the xml file I'm trying to parse is biblioteca.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<biblioteca>
    <libro>
        <titulo anyo="2008">Introduction to Linux</titulo>
        <autor>
            <nombre>Machtelt</nombre> 
            <nombre>Garrels</nombre>         
        </autor>
        <editor>O'Reilly</editor>
        <paginas>256</paginas>
    </libro>
    <libro>
        <titulo anyo="1991">El lenguaje de programación C</titulo>
        <autor>
            <nombre>Kernighan</nombre> 
            <nombre>Ritchie</nombre>
        </autor>
        <editor>Prentice Hall</editor>
        <paginas>294</paginas>
    </libro>
</biblioteca>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created the Libro instance but you have haven't set the values in it which is why it is outputting nulls.

You need to do this at end of the `getLibro()` method:

```
        Libro l1 = new Libro();
        l1.setAnyo(anyo);
        l1.setEditor(editor);
        l1.setPaginas(pags);
        l1.setTitulo(titulo);
        return l1;
```

Comment: Oh i can't believe i missed that; i still don't get the author but i supose is the same problem in other method, so thank you

Comment: No worries, we've all missed the simplest things. Sometimes it just needs a fresh pair of eyes.